# Is it possible to replace an implementation of a method of a dependency library in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, overwrite, java-compiler-api, javacompiler

We have a situation where we are using some library and we would like to customize the logic of a tiny private method used in the library. Unfortunately, the library isn't well written to be extended.

So basically, imagine if we have a library with the class `ClassA` like this one:

```
public class ClassA {

    public String buildMessage(){
        return "Hello, "+ buildSuffixString();
    }

    private String buildSuffixString(){
        return "World!";
    }
}
```

The class `ClassA` is used in the library by the class `ClassB`. `ClassB` is used in the library by `ClassC` and so on. `ClassB` creates its dependency in the constructor with the code like `classA = new ClassA()`; (Unfortunatelly). `ClassC` creates its dependency in the constructor with the code like `classB = new ClassB()`;. And so on.

We would like to force everyone who uses a method `buildMessage()` of `ClassA` to obtain `Hello, Kitty!` message instead of `Hello, World!` (i.e. we need to replace an implementation of the private method `buildSuffixString()` to our own implementation). Is there a way to change a logic of a private method by using reflection or Java compiler or something else?

Comment: [Apache Commons BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you a lot for the comment! I didn't know about this library. Do you have some example on how can we use this library to change the above code of the `buildSuffixString` method?

Comment: Quick Google foind: CDI Dependency Injection as part of Java EE